# Dependent dropdowns populated by sql database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have 3 drop-down lists on my page and a data-list. All of them are populated from SQL database based on selected item from previous drop-down.
AutoPostBack is set to true on all three dropdowns, and on first page load they are displayed correctly i.e. on all three dropdowns first item is selected and the result is displayed in data-list based on that selection. But when I change selection in the first drop-down, only second drop-down gets updated (sometimes it updates the third but its inconsistent), and to get the update on the third one I need to change the selection on the second one. The result in data-list mostly remains the same, and updates when I change selection in third drop-down.

What do I need to do to get the data-list updated when I change the selection in first drop down?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is difficult to advise anything sensible it will be just guess work. What happens when you debug the code? How are you rebinding the data on the postbacks? I am assuming you are using webforms here as well. Have you checked that you are not getting multiple events being fired off due to potentially an onchange event being fired off from the multiple dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Withoug looking at your code it is difficult to answer the question. But by looking at the description of your question, it looks like you are setting AutoPostBack=true, but not handling the OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

First of all you should add OnSelectedIndexChanged event for all the three dropdowns like below.

```
protected void dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

In each selectedindex changed event, you need to bind the next dropdown lists.
May be you can have one common function for binding the list view, which you need to call in each SelectedIndexChanged event.

If you just set AutoPostBack=true  and not handling the selectedindex changed, then it does not work properly as expected

Answer (score 0):

To get the data-list updated when the first drop-down is changed, you must fire the post-back event manually(for the second and 3rd drop-downs)!

Assuming the data on the 3rd drop-down is based on the selection from the 2nd,on the client Page in JavaScript : Try to have the first item or a default item selected. This would populate the 3rd list.

A good practice would be to have a default element, that is not specific!

It is also a matter of design. If its a typical list where the second and 3rd lists would be changed often locally, then it is best to have it pre-fetched and stored in a local Json object!

Answer (score 0):

to get the list populated on the selection_index changed of the first dropdown change. Call the populating method of the other two dropdown lists...

and on the selection_change event of the second dropdown call the populating method of the third dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Check your selectedIndexchanged method and whenever you are binding data to datalist before that clear the datalist items and then do binding. so you could have clear idea which data is not populating. and post your code here so it wolud give a clear idea